# Sublime text 3 - show number of bytes selected

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Sublime text 3 shows number of characters selected and number of lines..

I want to add a functionality for it to also show the number of bytes (or kb) on selected text.. The number is pretty straightforward from what I've found: number of bytes = number of characters + number of lines - 1

Is there a plugin or setting for that?

Comment: no, but it would be trivial to write a plugin.

Comment: "number of bytes = number of characters + number of lines - 1" Hmm. Depends on your EOL chars and whether it is unicode or not ....